# How to rename HEIC format to png/jpeg from folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

and I got an error **FileNotFoundError** that some file with some name not found but it there!

```
import os

directory = "/user/folder/"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    prefix = filename.split(".HEIC")[0]
    os.rename(filename, prefix + ".png")
```

Comment: `filename` does not contain the path (i.e., `directory`).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import os

directory = "/user/folder/"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    prefix = filename.split(".HEIC")[0]
    os.rename(filename, directory + prefix + ".png")
```

Comment: same crashed with FileNotFoundError